# Error message "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed"

Tags: vb.net

As far as I can remember this code that I got from a tutorial here works http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic-net/7258/adding-and-saving-records-access-database-using-vbnet.html

But now I don't know why I keep on getting this error but I already opened the connection. I have tried including cn.Open() on btnSave_Click event but instead I got the error Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. I tried installing this driver https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/3/24375141-E08D-4803-AB0E-10F2E3A07AAA/AccessDatabaseEngine.exe still no use.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Public cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader
Public Sub connection()
    cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\New folder\ProgramDraft4\Database6.accdb"
        .Open()
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call connection()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO ID (ID) VALUES (@ID)"
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ID", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txt1.Text))

            cm.Parameters("@ID").Value = Me.txt1.Text


            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Me.txt1.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It is also suggested to keep the connection open only when needed. This mean your btnSave function would open the connection and close is as soon as it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error message states clearly that you need an open connection so it should be obvious that you need to open the connection.  The second error message that you got when you actually opened the connection is a very common one.  If the user doesn't have Microsoft Office installed then need to installed the standalone ACE engine.

The biggest error here is installing the 32-bit edition of Office or ACE (which is preferred) and then running your application in a 64-bit process.  In that case, your app can't see the ACE engine so it reports it as not installed.  Go into the properties for your project and make sure that the target platform is set to x86, which will ensure that it runs in a 32-bit process on all systems.

EDIT:

Upon closer inspection, I see that you messed up your connection string.  You've specified the provider as `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0`, which doesn't exist.  If you're using an MDB file then you can specify `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` and use the Jet engine that comes with Windows.  If you're using an ACCDB file then you must specify `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and ensure that the ACE engine is installed as part of Office or standalone.

Comment: Did you perhaps install the 64-bit ACE engine then?

Comment: Ah, I just realised what you did.  I will update my answer.

Comment: The code I used already worked for me but one day when I created another program which is this the code doesn't work and my other program too.